# Unbound dependency injection giving could not be located error

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection

I am using unbound dependency injection, however, I still can't seem to inject the service:

```
// Interface
public interface IPublisherService<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    Task<TEntity> PublishAsync(TEntity entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

// Service
public class PublisherService<TEntity> : IPublisherService<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IPublishEndpoint _publishEndpoint;

    protected PublisherService(ILogger<PublisherService<TEntity>> logger, IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint)
    {
        this._logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        this._publishEndpoint = publishEndpoint ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(publishEndpoint));
    }
    
    public async Task<TEntity> PublishAsync(TEntity entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            await _publishEndpoint.Publish(entity, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Could not send message to queue Reason: {ex.Message}");
        }
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Then I register it like such:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtension
{
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterPublishers(this IServiceCollection services) => services
        .AddScoped(typeof(IPublisherService<>), typeof(PublisherService<>));
}

...

builer.Services.RegisterPublishers();
```

The error I get when trying to inject it into a controller is as such:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'Marel.Livestock.MassTransit.Publisher.Services.Generics.PublisherService`1[Marel.Livestock.Models.TestClass.TheTestClass]' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.

```
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateOpenGeneric(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot, Boolean throwOnConstraintViolation)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateOpenGeneric(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method10(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
```

Comment: Please also show us your concrete implementation of the service which is causing the problem.

Comment: Injection constructors should be public; yours is protected. Most DI Containers work this way and MS.DI certainly requires this.

Comment: And what do you mean by "unbound dependency injection"?

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith there is no concrete implementation... that's the point of unbound dependency injection.

Comment: @Steven you were correct. You can answer and I'll accept. Worked perfectly after that.

Comment: @Steven unbound DPI is when there is no concrete implementation. This code shows how to do it:

`.AddScoped(typeof(IPublisherService<>), typeof(PublisherService<>))`

Comment: #CorrieJanse: Thanks for clearing that up. Interesting; I was unfamiliar with this terminology. As far as I can tell (after some Googling), this terminology originates from (a book by) Anders Hejlsberg (the original designer of C#), but the terminology doesn't seem to be adapter by the C# team itself, as their documentation primarily uses the terminology "open" and "closed" to describe generic types. From perspective of DI, talking about "unbound DI" might be a little confusing though, or at least it was for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message actually contains the answer to your problem:

> A suitable constructor for type 'Marel.Livestock.MassTransit.Publisher.Services.Generics.PublisherService`1[Marel.Livestock.Models.TestClass.TheTestClass]' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters **of a public constructor**.

Your class doesn't have a public constructor; its constructor is protected, which is why the type can't be resolved. The problem, therefore, is unrelated to the use of generics.

Unfortunately, the provided message by MS.DI is a bit confusing. You probably wouldn't have posted your question here if the container provided you with the following message instead:

> A suitable constructor for type PublisherService could not be located. Ensure the type has a public constructor.